# How to delete row in ordered list with lesser SQL queries

Tags: go, sqlc

Context - I need help with writing SQL queries and use [sqlc](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc) for generating corresponding go code to execute them.

My table of items looks like this.

| ID | Name | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | apple | 1 |
| 107 | ball | 2 |
| 110 | cat | 3 |
| 111 | dog | 4 |

I am writing a delete API which deletes an item and should update the positions of the remaining items so there are no gaps. For example, after I delete `ball`, I would like the table to look like

| ID | Name | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | apple | 1 |
| 110 | cat | 2 |
| 111 | dog | 3 |

In other words - it should delete the target item and reduce the position of all the items with positions greater than that of the target item by one.

Below is the way I am currently doing it -

```
-- GetItem: one
SELECT * from items WHERE id=?;

-- name: DeleteItem:execrows
DELETE FROM items WHERE id = ?;

-- name: UpdatePositions: execrows
UPDATE items SET position = position - 1
WHERE item.position > sqlc.arg(position);
```

And calling the functions shown -

```
item, _ := GetItem(id)
_, _ := DeleteItem(id)
_, _ := UpdatePositions(item.position)
```

I am first getting the item to be deleted to get its position, deleting the item, and executing an update command with the position found in the first step. I want to reduce the function calls I make for this delete operation.

#### Questions -

1. Can I execute the DELETE and UPDATE commands using a single generated function, which sqlc understands? So, execute two SQL statements with one generated function?
2. Can I omit the `GetItem` call by writing a single SQL statement to get and update item positions?

I tried writing an update command which selects the target widget and gets its position, and updates the rows with greater positions than that. But it resulted in an sqlc error.

Comment: 1. Yes, you could write a stored procedure that you could then call. 2. Yes, if you passed the id to the stored procedure you could accomplish all your operations in one go

Comment: Note that these operations _must_ be performed in a single transaction (unless your system built in a way that whatever service you're writing has exclusive access to the DBMS at all times). If you first update positions, and then delete the item, you might write the update statement in a way that it fetches the position of the item-to-be-deleted right in the query. Of course, if you have a unique constraint on the Position column, it won't work.